# How to stack n divs vertically to n width?

Tags: css

I have been given a design with a number of variable height items stacked vertically in a fixed height container, with a variable width. So the idea is that the items can scroll off screen (will be in a wrapper) so that they can be scrolled horizontally onto screen.

I'm having trouble coming up with a solid way of organising the divs so that they stack reliably. Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Vertically stacking variable height items]

Comment: Are you allowed to use javascript?

Comment: @ladaghini I think it might have to be yes! I'm just writing a loop in jQuery at the moment to calculate the `outerHeight()` and add it up, in order to 'break' the columns inside the container.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest pretty much the same thing, except also update the `column-count` to the number needed.

Comment: After refreshing this page, it seems that the one answerer has deleted his solution. Here's what I got going from his fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uNwFM/5/.

Comment: Well, the answer's still there. Anyways, I tested it on Firefox too. It works (automatically adds columns as needed) except there is no gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uNwFM/8/)

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div style="height: 100px;"> 1 </div>
    <div style="height: 50px;"> 2 </div>
    <div style="height: 150px;"> 3 </div>
    <div style="height: 300px;"> 4 </div>
    <div style="height: 50px;"> 5 </div>
    <div style="height: 100px;"> 6 </div>
    <div style="height: 100px;"> 7 </div>
    <div style="height: 70px;"> 8 </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
       -moz-column-count: 3;
            column-count: 3;

    height: 400px;
    background: beige;
}


div {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px;
    background: orange;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't create as many columns as needed, only 3; it doesn't even have a fixed `height`.

Comment: Ah I see. I was unaware that the column count was basically irrelevant. I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this situation before, and I couldn't find any solution other than using Javascript. Follows an example script that uses **jQuery**, which assumes that initially all `<div>`s are stacked in one table-cell.

```
var maxH = 600; //can be anything
function fix() {
    var row = document.getElementById("tbl").rows[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < row.cells.length; i ++) {
        var cur = row.cells[i];
        if($(cur).height() > maxH) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
            newcell.vAlign = "top";
            newcell.style.paddingLeft = "10px";
            while($(cur).height() > maxH) {
               $(cur).children().last().detach().appendTo(newcell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYQMe/15/).